# How to measure memory allocation time in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, static, heap-memory

I need to do the following:

1. Write three functions in C++
2. one function declares a large array STATICALLY
3. one function declares the same array on a STACK
4. and the last function creates the same array from the HEAP
5. Each subprogram must be called a large number of times (100,000)
6. Output the time required by each

Here's my code:

**USER ENVIRONMENT**

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func1();
void func2();
void func3();

int main()
{

    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        func1();
        func2();
        func3();
    }
}
```

**IMPLEMENTATION**

```
void func1()
{
    int static my_array[1000];
}

void func2()
{
    int my_array[1000];
}

void func3()
{
    new int my_array[1000];
}
```

Questions:

- Do I create the array in the Main or in each Function (like I've done)?
- Do I find the Time in the Main or in each Function?
- Is it Time() or Clock()?
- Do I have to save the Time() to a variable?
- What have I done wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: It would be clock(). I know that. And you would need to save the start of the call to a variable. `float start_time = clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;`, would be just before the for loop. `float end time = clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` would be just after the for loop. and `cout << start_time - end_time << endl;` or `printf("Time taken: %f s.", start_time - end_time);` to print the output.

Comment: You are asking questions that would be better answered by your teacher or T.A. that assigned you this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) you can create the array inside function as you have mentioned in example so that you can determine how much time each function has taken to allocate memory for array.

b) You need determine time taken by between each function call. other wise what's the point in determining in each loop.

You can use  to determine time diff in milliseconds.

```
 typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
        typedef std::chrono::milliseconds milliseconds;
        Clock::time_point t0 = Clock::now();
         fun1(); //function call
        Clock::time_point t1 = Clock::now();
        milliseconds ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(t1 - t0);
        std::cout << ms.count() << "ms\n";
```

Similarly you can determine how much time it took for remaining function call.